# Unity3D game touch issue when adding subviews to the UnityGetGLView()

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, uiview, touch

In game I take touch inputs from the user. This is the code on Unity side to get touches:

```
foreach (Touch t in Input.touches) {
    if(t.position.x < Screen.width / 2){
        GameManager.isPlayerActive[0] = true;
    }
    else{
        GameManager.isPlayerActive[1] = true;
    }
}
```

It was all fine at first. Now I'm on my stage of integrating ads in the game. On xCode side I added Mopub SDK and implemented delegates for banner ad:

```
- (void)adViewDidLoadAd:(MPAdView *)view{
    if(![UnityGetGLViewController().view.subviews containsObject:view]){
        [UnityGetGLViewController().view addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

The test ad displays OK. Whenever I touch the ad view (blue area) and hold it sliding around my touch is mapped to the screen like this:

[image: weird touch remap]

the 'X's on the bottom represent the actual touch but Unity thinks they are on screen.

**More details:**

this behaviour is occurring ONLY if the touch starts on the ad view.

If the user starts touch on the banner view than the touch does not work in the game view any more and other way around.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?
Thanks!